# spark null pointer exception for customzied filter unftion

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a customzied filter function writtern as:

```
def filterSpiderBots(inputDF: DataFrame, whitelistMatcher: Matcher) {
    val filterFunc = udf(
       (ua:String) => ua == null || whitelistMatcher.matches(ua) 
    )
    inputDF.filter(filterFunc($"ua"))
}
```

The matcher reads from

```
FileInputStream(SparkFiles.get("iab-whitelist.txt"))
```

I made sure the Match is not null, and I have a check for null ua in place.
but when I start the program, I still get NullPointerException. I don't know what is the cause of it..

Update:

after not use matcher, i still get the same error

```
def filterSpiderBots(inputDF: DataFramer) {
    val filterFunc = udf(
       (ua:String) => ua == null 
    )
    inputDF.filter(filterFunc($"ua"))
}
```

Comment: What is `whitelistMatcher` / `Matcher`?

Comment: it's a serialized class, used for filter process

Comment: Does it reference spark or sql context / session?

Comment: it doesn't refer sql context / session. But it reads a file by calling SparkFiles.get("iab-whitelist.txt"), i updated the question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

filter() preserves records that evaluate to true .. and in your case, all the null records evaluate to true. So, change your filterFunc to "ua != null" ?

Comment: I get null pointer exception when the program runs, it's not about the output

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?